# Primefaces tooltip for a datatable row

Tags: primefaces, tooltip, primefaces-extensions

I need to auto display a tooltip on some rows of my datatable , without any event, i've read the that it can be done using Primefaces Extensions, but could not find an example that works.
I don't know what value should take the attribute forSelector.

```
<pe:tooltip value="Click to view More Datails"
forSelector="?" shared="true"
targetPosition="top center" position="left center"
autoShow="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to display a tooltip for a row in datatable, here after an exemple:

```
<pe:tooltip forSelector=".myTable tr[role=row][data-ri=#{rowIndex}]" value="#{project['myfield.tooltip']} #{obj.myfield}"/>
```

Where:

- .myTable is a css style applied to the datatable:
  `styleClass="myTable"`
- rowIndex is the row index var defined in datatable:
  `rowIndexVar="rowIndex"`

this tooltip is to be added inside a `<p:column>`.

Note that to be able to use Primefaces Extensions tags, you should add the appropriate xmlns:

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set autoshow property true

```
 <pe:tooltip value="AutoShow" autoShow="true"/>
```

you can bind this property to backingbean value...

```
 <p:column id="ctipo3" headerText="Estado">                                                        
        <p:commandButton id="estado"/>
         <pe:tooltip id="toolTipTrack4" for="estado" value="#{item.texto}" autoShow="#{item.texto}"/>
 </p:column>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i already tested with the `autoShow="true"` and it didn't work in my case (datatable row).